# Gridview selected item keep highlighted and confirm image

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I am developing an android app with `GridView`.  The gridView contains buttons. I have customized my gridView with button adapter.

The question is: I need to keep the selected item highlighted with borders. Now the selection is disappearing after releasing the press.
 I am not an expert in android. So the next step after pressing the button is to display an image of cloud shape that says "confirm".

[This](https://plus.google.com/photos/103076464130813961822/albums/5872200152448965537/5872200159842196482?hl=en&utm_source=lmnavbr&utm_medium=embd&utm_campaign=lrnmre&rtsl=1) is what I exactly needed.

Comment: i have tried setSelection(true).I dont have the concept that's why I couldn't do anything else.Can you please suggest a method I have the selector in the drawable folder

Comment: greenDroid on github have a somthing like that. you should try this. https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid .first see the images then try to implement this

Comment: also go for popups. http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/

Comment: @qadir I think you are mistaken i need to re position the popup when user clicks one button that popup should be above the pressed button. i have a doubt is that when a popup appeared can we press another button in the row.?

Comment: @qadir Sorry qadir. I know you didnt understood my comment. The thing is that suppose we have one row of buttons. When user pressing the first button the popup should be above the first button and after pressing the first one user decides to press the second button. Then the border and popup should appear on the second button.Hope you got it.

Comment: yes I misunderstood and then got it :) you have take care of the focus. if a user clicks the area besides the popup it should dismiss that popup and opens an other one and also set border to other button.

Comment: @Qadir Can you please provide me a sample code ?

Comment: @Sruty you should accept answer

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder named `drawable` in your `res` folder. Now create a `xml` file in `drawable` folder, name it anything (in small laters) and put this code in the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"><shape>

            <!-- <solid android:color="#CCCCCC"/> -->

            <gradient android:endColor="#67A7F8" android:startColor="#1067C8" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"><shape>

            <!-- <solid android:color="#07B107"/> -->

            <gradient android:endColor="#67A7F8" android:startColor="#1067C8" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#0055FF" />

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:centerColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFF" android:startColor="#F2F2F2" />

            <stroke android:width="0.8dp" android:color="#000000" />

            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"><shape>
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

now in your  `GridView` code set  `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` and  `android:listSelector` properties and select the `drawable` you have just created. It will resolve your problem.

Your grid view code will look something like this :

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/lstFrames_available_frames"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/round_buttons"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >
    </GridView>
```

**UPDATE**
You can use something like this in your custom adapter to achieve what you want :

```
public class AlbumCoverAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    private int mSelected;

    public AlbumCoverAdapter(Activity a) {
        activity = a;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 50;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txtCaption;

        public ImageView imgImage;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtCaption = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtGridText);
            holder.txtCaption.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    mSelected = (Integer)arg0.getTag();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        try {
            holder.txtCaption.setTag(position);

            if (position == mSelected) {
                holder.txtCaption.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_corner_background);
            } else {
                holder.txtCaption.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

            }

            holder.txtCaption.setText("Item: " + position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry Vipul :( again the same problem it disappearing the selection.Not Highlighting

Comment: Sorry Vipull.. :(Nothing happened

Comment: Ok finally can you please add *** android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" ***
property in you grid view? Because this is working in my code.

Comment: Can you please provide me the sample code.? then it will be very useful  to me. thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing special in code. These are the important parts.

Comment: Ok will send you later at night. :)

Comment: Hey can you add you grid adapter code here?. I think you problem can be solved by changing in adapter.

Comment: Vipul I had sent you a mail please check that. I couldnt post the code here due to some editing problem.

Comment: Hey i hope you got the mail.

Comment: I have send you an email with sample application. please check it

Comment: Vipul Thanks for solving one problem. :)

Comment: Hey How can i avoid the default selection..?

Comment: mail me too please -_-